# Conexion java Postgres en Netbeans

Tags: java, postgresql

Quisiera hacerles una consulta, la verdad es que  soy nuevo en esto, soy un estudiante de programación y tengo un pequeño proyecto.

Actualmente estoy realizando un programa donde se puedan almacenar  los datos de las personas, en NetBeans.
Mi pregunta es: ¿Como genero la conexión a la base de datos entre postgres y Java? ¿Cómo genero los queries para que cuando seleccione el botón de guardar info se guarde en la  base de datos de postgres?

Comment: Es pregunta es muy amplia, prueba buscando primero tutoriales de conexión java con postgres, ya que la respuesta adecuada para tu pregunta es muy amplia para este formato

Comment: @jasilva  Muchas gracias  !  La verdad es que si eh buscado pero  son uchas alternativas que no se cual tomar.....

Comment: Te reqcomiendo que mires tutorialspoint regularmente sus tutoriales son buenos y estan actualizados, este es el que tu necesitas http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_java.htm , tambien siempre es bueno leer la documentación oficial y necesitas descargar el dirver https://jdbc.postgresql.org/

Comment: Muchas gracias @jasilva    y si lo del driver lo tengo muy presente ... algo avia investigado al respecto.......

Comment: @jasilva  Esta super bien la pagina de tutorialspoint te lo agradezco.... muy preciso !

Answer (score 3):

En realidad creo que es bastante sencillo y hay bastante información, te dare un poco de información, suponiendo tienes tu base de datos puedes realizarlo con JDBC, puedes descargar el .jar desde:
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Este sería un ejemplo básico, solo configura tu base de datos real, usuario y password:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public void realizaConexion(){
            Connection conn = null;
            String urlDatabase =  "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:0000/midatabase"; 
            try {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDatabase,  "usuario", "password");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Ocurrio un error : "+e.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.println("La conexión se realizo sin problemas! =) ");
}
```

Una tutorial que es excelente pero viene en inglés, es:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_java.htm

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Como genero la conexión a la base de datos entre postgres y Java?

Tienes dos maneras de hacerlo. La primera que es abrir la conexión manualmente. Este, a su vez, tiene dos maneras, dependiendo si el driver de conexión a tu base de datos soporta JDBC 4 o no.

Si **no soporta** JDBC 4 debe ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String urlDatabase =  "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/midatabase";
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); //cargar el driver manualmente
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDatabase,  "usuario", "password");
}
```

Si el driver soporta JDBC 4 entonces ya no necesitas cargar la clase, por lo que el código se reduce:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String urlDatabase =  "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/midatabase";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDatabase,  "usuario", "password");
}
```

Esta primera forma sirve para aplicaciones pequeñas de consola, de escritorio, personales o "de juguete". Para aplicaciones que vas a enviar a producción, que piensas vender, que deben ser más profesionales, **no debes** utilizar la primera forma, puesto que cada vez que se ejecuta `DriverManager#getConnection` se abre una conexión física al motor de base de datos (operación costosa) y cada vez que se cierra la conexión vía `Connection#close` se cierra esta conexión física. La ejecución de esta operación múltiples veces afecta el rendimiento de la aplicación. Por ello, la solución es utilizar un pool de conexiones a través de la interfaz [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html). Ojo, hay otras librerías que ya implementan esta interfaz y almacenan las conexiones de manera que no necesitas reinventar la rueda. Para lograr esto, utilizas una de dos opciones:

1. Si tu aplicación o aplicaciones van a residir en un servidor de aplicaciones (JBoss, Wildfly, WebLogic, IBM Was, etc.) o un contenedor de servlets (Tomcat, Jersey, etc.), puedes configurar un pool de conexiones y luego obtenerlo vía JNDI. La configuración del pool de conexiones depende de cada servidor de aplicaiones o contenedor de servlets, pero en tu código Java obtendrías la conexión de esta manera:

   ```
   public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
       final String DATASOURCE_CONTEXT = "..."; //nombre de tu pool de conexiones
       Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
       DataSource datasource = (DataSource)initialContext.lookup(DATASOURCE_CONTEXT);
       return datasource.getConnection();
   }
   ```
2. Si tu aplicación se ejecuta en consola, en escritorio o simplemente no te gusta depender de configurar el pool de conexiones en el contenedor, entonces puedes utilizar un `DataSource`. La implementación de esta interfaz va a abrir un grupo de conexiones físicas a las base de datos y mantenerlas abiertas mientras que tu aplicación siga ejecutándose, de manera que puedes reutilizar las conexiones en múltiples operaciones. Esto incrementa el rendimiento de tu aplicación.

   Existen varias librerías que proveen esta funcionalidad como HikariCP, C3PO, Apache Commons DBCP, etc. Básicamente, proveen una clase que implementa la interfaz `DataSource` de manera que terminas llamando a esta instancia y obteniendo la conexión de allí directamente. Aquí un ejemplo con [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) (personalmente, mi favorito). La configuración se realiza de la siguiente manera:

   ```
   public DataSource getDataSource() {
       HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
       config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/midatabase");
       config.setUsername("usuario");
       config.setPassword("password");
       config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
       config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
       config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");

       HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
   }

   public Connection getConnection(DataSource dataSource) {
       return dataSource.getConnection();
   }
   ```

   El diseño de arriba permite: un método para crear el `DataSource` y que el cliente de dicha clase asegure que se cree una sola vez. Luego, el método de abajo permite utilizar una instancia de `DataSource` para obtener la conexión. Un ejemplo utilizando como base el código anterior y utilizando singleton sería:

   ```
   //los enum en Java son singleton por defecto
   public enum ConexionesBaseDatos {
       private final DataSource dataSource;
       POSTGRES;

       private ConexionesBaseDatos() {
           dataSource = getDataSource("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/midatabase", "usuario", "password");
       }

       private DataSource getDataSource(String constr, String usuario, String password) {
           HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
           config.setJdbcUrl(constr);
           config.setUsername(usuario);
           config.setPassword(password);
           config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
           config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
           config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");

           HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
       }

       public Connection getConnection() {
           return dataSource.getConnection();
       }
   }
   ```

   Ten en cuenta que este diseño es solo un ejemplo. Pueden haber otras maneras de conseguirlo, y utilizando frameworks de inyección de dependencias como Spring o Guice se consigue un diseño distinto y más flexible.

### IMPORTANTE

Sea el método que elijas para obtener tu instancia de `Connection`, **SIEMPRE** debes cerrar la conexión utilizada, es decir, **SIEMPRE** debes llamar al método `Connection#close`. Un ejemplo:

```
Connection conn = null;
try {
    conn = getConnection(); //utilizando cualquiera de los métodos de arriba
    //usar la variable con...
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

O usando `try-with-resources` desde Java 7, donde el bloque `try` puede llamar automáticamente al método `close` por ti, sería de esta forma:

```
try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {
    //usar la variable conn...
}
```

Cuando se llama `Connection#close` desde el primer método, la conexión física a la base de datos se cierra. Cuando se llama desde el segundo método, la conexión física regresa al pool de conexiones, habilitando la conexión para ser reutilizada en llamadas subsecuentes.

> ¿Cómo genero los queries para que cuando seleccione el botón de guardar info se guarde en la base de datos de postgres?

Tienes que generar los queries manualmente. Java y JDBC no conocen la estructura de tu tabla y no saben cómo se deben insertar los campos. Para ello, si vas a trabajar con JDBC, puedes utilizar el siguiente diseño:

```
public class EntidadDao {

    public Connection conn;

    public EntidadDao(Connection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    public void guardaEntidad(Entidad entidad) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO entidad (nombre, description) VALUES (?, ?)";
        try (PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql) {
            pstmt.setString(1, entidad.getNombre());
            pstmt.setString(2, entidad.getDescripcion());
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //lanzar RuntimeException para tener código más limpio
            throw new RuntimeException("Error al guardar entidad.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class EntidadServicio {

    public void guardaEntidad(Entidad entidad) {
        Connection conn = null;
        try (conn = ConexionesBaseDatos.POSTGRES.getConnection()) {
            //iniciar una transacción, buena práctica
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            //abrir un bloque de manejo de excepciones
            try {
                //creas todos los Daos con la misma conexión para manejar
                //la misma transacción
                EntidadDao entidadDao = new EntidadDao(conn);
                entidadDao.guardaEntidad(entidad);
                //si todo funcionó sin problemas, se realiza el commit
                conn.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //si hubo algún problema, se realiza un rollback
                conn.rollback();
            }
            //se cierra la transacción
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Recuerda que el diseño presentado aquí es básico, debe servir como base para crear un diseño más adecuado a tu aplicación. Asimismo, si utilizas frameworks de inyección de dependencias como Spring o Guice, se puede lograr un diseño más desacoplado entre las clases.

Existen frameworks como Hibernate y JPA que pueden crear los scripts de `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `SELECT` por ti de acuerdo a la estructura de la tabla, pero es demasiada información para esta respuesta.

Comment: Hola @Luiggi muchas gracias por tu aporte ... de verdad te lo agradesco

Comment: Hola miren encontre este codigo en tuturialespoint .....  la aplicacion que estoy haciendo en la escuela es un punto de venta fictisio para un consultorio  optico en el cual me pide guardar en un expediente los datos de los pacientes....

Answer (score 1):

La conexion se hace se la siguiente manera y cambian unas lineas segun el manejador de bases de datos
introducir el código aquí

public class Conexion {

```
private static  String user="pas";
private static String contrasenia="contra";
private static final String JDBC_driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.";
private static Driver driver;
private static  String db="databaseName=FUCS";
private static final String url_JDBC="jdbc:sqlserver://BaseDeDatos;"+db;

public Conexion(){

}


public static  synchronized Connection  getConexion() throws SQLException{
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
    //if(driver==null){
        //try{
          //  Class JdbcDriverClass=Class.forName(JDBC_driver);
            //driver= (Driver) JdbcDriverClass.newInstance();
        //}catch(Exception ex){
          //  System.err.println("errorororoor");
        //ex.printStackTrace();
       // }
    //}
return DriverManager.getConnection(url_JDBC,user,contrasenia);
}



public static void close(PreparedStatement stat){
try{
    if(stat!=null){
        stat.close();
    }
}catch(SQLException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void close(ResultSet set){
```

try{
       if(set!=null){
       set.close();
       }
     }catch(SQLException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

```
public static void close(Connection co){
    try{
    if(co!=null){
    co.close();
    }
    }catch(SQLException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Esto es algo a lo que nos hemos enfrentado la mayoría. Te recomiendo dos cosas:

1- La información que buscas te juro que está por todos lados, no te preocupes, no es una duda tan extraña.

2- En lugar de usar las query "a pelo", busca cómo hacerlo con Hibernate. Hibernate lo que hace es guardar el objeto "persona" como tal, en lugar de guardar los datos y pasarlos por la query.

Tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo, en este caso con MySQL en mi repositorio de bitbucket. Está todo licenciado en GPL V2, así que puedes tomarlo y modificarlo sin problemas. bitbucket.org/dosz.

Espero sinceramente que te haya podido ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

```
package Conexión;
import java.sql.*;
//UTLIZARÉ LA PRIMERA FORMA DE CONExión(url,user,password)

public class Conectando_a_Postgres {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection cn;
    String url= "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cliente_03_06_18";
    String user= "postgres";
    String password= "123456";        
  try{
     Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
     cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
     System.out.println("CONEXIÓN ESTABLECIDA");
  }

catch(Exception e) 
  {
      System.out.println("Error de conexión"+e.getMessage());
  }  


    }

}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu aporte, las respuestas que contienen código unicamente son consideradas de baja calidad, considera agregar una descripción de como esta respuesta soluciona el problema y a la vez proporciona una solución diferente a las respuestas que ya existen, lee **[answer]**